# Getting database errors after adding files in web.config transformation process

Tags: sql, visual-studio, azure-devops

I need three config files under webconfig for three different environments i.e QA,Pre-PROD,PROD. I have added through configuration manager in VSTS and built successfully and pushed in Azure devops repo then tried to build it.Its throwing database error. Please suggest me how to add three webconfig files without getting threse errors. In build pipeline we are using Visual studio build and In release pipeline IIS web app deploy task and enable XML transformation
[![Please see the picture for scrrenshot of task and settings][1]][1]
[![Build pipeline][2]][2]

```
XXXX.Database.Deployment\dbo\Views\ProjectLocations.sql(51,1): Error SQL70015: Stored procedure 'XXXX' is not supported for the targeted platform.

XXXX.Database.Deployment\dbo\Tables\DataAccessRequests.sql(26,5): Error SQL70015: Keyword or statement option 'XXXX' is not supported for the targeted platform.
XXXX.Database.Deployment\dbo\Tables\PermissionRequests.sql(30,5): Error SQL70015: Keyword or statement option 'XXXX' is not supported for the targeted platform.

XXXX.Database.Deployment\dbo\Views\vDataAccessRequestDetails.sql(33,6): Error SQL71501: View: [dbo].[vDataAccessRequestDetails] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[DataAccessRequests].
```

Comment: Which task are you using but facing this error? You added the procedure into the web.config, right? Could you update with details that how to you configured in the web.config? Better with the task configuration.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Please find my updated question

Comment: Is that a build error or a deployment error? As you described in the question, you mentioned it is a build error, little confused here.

Comment: If convenient, you can share your log with email to me. For security, you can cover your private strings.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT .It's a build error